# Regex: the last word should much 'LTD' or 'inc' or 'gmbh'

Tags: regex

Hi i'm looking for the regular expression to detect whether the last word of the string matches one of 'LTD' or 'inc' or 'gmbh'

**Note:** the solution that split the string in any way not good.

Comment: `\b(?:LTD|inc|gmbh)$`?

Answer (score 1):

```
/\b(LTD|inc|gmbh)\W*$/
```

Test it: http://rubular.com/r/3eStQUntgE

But I would recommend also trowing in some case insensitivity:

```
/\b(ltd|inc|gmbh)\W*$/i
```